# Is node required for deploying Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is there a way to directly deploy cloud functions for firebase via the webpage or must I use node. All my searching hasn't found anything but I want to be certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need node, because you need npm, npm is node package manager. Node Package Manager will install the CLI and then run other commands needed to deploy.

Is a bit tricky because npm is an installer, so why can't I get npm without node? Because npm use node, since it is node package installer.

After that npm and node, will keep working together to run the simple commands, like deploying to Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Node is required for running the Firebase command-line interface, which is the tool you use to deploy Cloud Functions for Firebase.

Comment: Thank you, do you know why it must be like that

Comment: @user7951676 — It doesn't have to be like that. The authors just decided to do it that way.

Comment: Makes sense though why wouldn't it run in a browser if modified slightly